# Spring Entity is null although I use the new operator

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I dont know why the object is null. This in an entity in my project. I am Using Spring, Lombok, Hibernate and Vaadin. I want to instanciate a new Group. This in my entity class:

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = { "groupSid" })
@Table(name = "ad_group")

public class Group implements Comparable<Group> {

@Id
@Column(name = "group_sid")
private String groupSid;

private String name;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "memberOf", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<Person> persons;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "group", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
private Set<Authority> authorities;

@Column(name = "jira_ticket_id")
private String ticketId;

@Override
public int compareTo(Group o) {
   return getName().compareTo(o.getName());
}

@Override
public String toString() {
   return name;
 }

}
```

In the edit dialog for the group I use the follwing code to persist the group details.

```
     btnSave.addClickListener(e -> {

     Group toSave = new Group();
     System.out.println("toSave: " + toSave);
     toSave.setGroupSid(selectedGroup.getGroupSid());
     toSave.setTicketId(tfTicket.getValue());
     if (toSave != null) {
        Group savedGroup = service.saveGroup(toSave);
        if (savedGroup != null) {
           parentView.updateUsers(selectedPerson, null, savedGroup);
        }
     }

     close();
  });
```

When the code is executed it shows this ouput:

```
  toSave: null
```

How can the group be null? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: in the console...

Comment: I meant, where in the code x) I couldn't see the pintln. I saw that now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The object itself is not `null` only `name`  is `null`

and that's why

```
@Override
public String toString() {
   return name;
 }
```

returns `null`.

And this method is called implicitly in the System.out.println statement

`System.out.println("toSave: " + toSave);`

Answer (score 2):

When you create an object,the object is not null.But the name is `null`.

```
System.out.println("toSave: " + toSave);
```

The above code will execute the toString method,the name will be printed.It returns `null`.